# PySpark evaluate formula stored in a DataSet column, using values from another DataSet

Tags: python, pyspark, dataset

I have a Dataset (main) storing a formula in a column:

```
ID | Formula
1    (a/(b+c))*100
2    m/n*100
3    d
```

And another Dataset (val) containing the values:

```
ID  |  Value
a      4
b      3
c      8
d      7
m      2
n      5
```

I need to evaluate the formula using the values from the val dataset, and save the result into a new main column.

I did this by iterating line by line through the main Dataset, create a variable storing a list with all the formula parameters, replace the parameter with values and evaluate. Then I used .withColumn to add the result to the main Dataset.
But this is not optimal at all for large amounts of data.

Could you please help me with a hint of how can I do this without iterating line by line ?

Thank you!

Comment: what functions could show in the Formula, SQL-based or Python-based? can the variable names be non-alphanum, i.e. underscore, dot etc? what is the size of the 2nd dataframe, or is the number of variables a limited or a huge list?

Comment: The functions are SQL-based. Yes the variable names contains dot, the format is: abcd.123 . The 2nd dataframe contains around 40k lines. Anyway I need to use 4 condition to filter the 2nd dataframe, before matching the variables values.

Comment: IMO, it will be much easier if they're Python codes,as we can use `eval()` (even though it might not be safe), there is not such thing in SQL. the `dot` in variable names will be an issue though since it's hard to separate them away from a floating number. from my testing, for simple + - * /, udf should be fine, Math functions like `sin()`, `pi` etc, I am getting error/null return. it looks eval function does not work well when using imported functions under Spark context. will have to check more on this..

Comment: I managed to do it with eval(), and it's working. But before using eval, I replaced the code with values: FormulaVal = FormulaCode.replace(code, str(value)) . Then just use eval(FormulaVal) and it's working.

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to make it work with both pandas_udf and udf when I explicitly import these math functions inside the function. (got NameError when import from the main, got the same error when switching to rdd-based map/mapPartition methods). so from my current testing so far, as long as the SQL functions or syntax can find a replacement in Python, it should be able to be evaluated using Python-based udf functions :)